# D3 label on a line in forced graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, force-layout

There is example how to have a label on the node in a D3 forced graph. What I try to do is to have a label on the line instead.

Example of the label on node: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022

This code will display the text for the line up in the left corner. It seems that it takes the x, y cordinates from the canvas and not from my line. How to fix this?

> var labelLine = olinks.append("text")
>                          .attr("x", 12)
>                          .attr("dy", ".35em")
>                          .text("eeeeee");

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .node {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: .6;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="./Script/d3.v3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var graph = {
        "nodes": [
          { "name": "App1-main", "group": 1 },
          { "name": "App2", "group": 1 },
          { "name": "App3", "group": 1 },
          { "name": "App4", "group": 1 },
          { "name": "Content-1", "group": 3 },
          { "name": "Content-1", "group": 3 },
          { "name": "Content-1", "group": 3 },
          { "name": "Content-1", "group": 3 },
          { "name": "Pontmercy", "group": 3 }
        ],
        "links": [
          { "source": 1, "target": 0, "value": 1 },
          { "source": 2, "target": 0, "value": 1 },
          { "source": 0, "target": 3, "value": 1 }
        ]
    };
    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-300)
        .linkDistance(60)
        .size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var drawGraph = function (graph) {
        force
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links)
            .start();

        var olinks = svg.selectAll("g.link")
            .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("g")
            .call(force.drag);

        var link = olinks.append("line")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value);    });

        var labelLine = olinks.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 12)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .text("eeeeee");

        var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
           .data(graph.nodes)
           .enter()
           .append('g')
           .classed('gnode', true);

        var node = gnodes.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
            .call(force.drag);

        var labels = gnodes.append("text")
                        .attr("x", 12)
                        .attr("dy", ".35em")
                        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

        console.log(labels);

        force.on("tick", function () {
            link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

            gnodes.attr("transform", function (d) {
                return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')';
            });



        });
    };

    drawGraph(graph);

 </script>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924990/how-can-i-append-text-to-and-render-that-text-from-a-line-in-a-force-directed-gr)?

Comment: Why it is that you allways find the answer to the question 1 min after you have posted a question even if you been looking for it for days?

This example answer this. http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2879486

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/689Qj/) is an example that has correct behavior.

The key points are here:

1) You need to define link as SVG "g" element, so that you can define both lines and labels for each link, and that coordinates are computed correctly.

2) Label text must be centered horizontally (code: `.attr("text-anchor", "middle"`)).

3) Inside tick(), you need to compute coordinate of the labels., as arithmetic mean between source and target node.

Hope this helps.

There also was [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470330/add-label-to-the-link-in-force-directed-graph/23471490#23471490) recently.