# d3 graph: how to append text to only a given link

Tags: d3.js

Please see

bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

Click anywhere in the canvas. It creates a new node. Drag mouse from one node to another. It creates an arrow between the nodes. I want that a text should be displayed as label of an arrow just after the arrow is created. Text should be appended only to that arrow. What code to add in that and where?

See the following lines of code in the example (bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) I mentioned:

```
link = {source: source, target: target, left: false, right: false};
    link[direction] = true;
    links.push(link);
```

Just after that, I added the following

```
linkLabels = svg.selectAll("link").data(links).enter()
    .append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x)/2; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y)/2; })
.text(function(d) {return (d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id);});
```

It appends text but the problem is that everytime a link is created, it appends text to that link and also to all other links. Because of this, text is appended to many links several times.
I want that the text should only be appended to the just created link. How to do that? I even replaced 'link' by '.link' but now no text is displayed.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a force directed graph. Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924990/how-can-i-append-text-to-and-render-that-text-from-a-line-in-a-force-directed-gr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
linkLabels = svg.selectAll("link").data(links).enter()
```

Are you sure you want to compute data joins for `<link>` elements? Those are used for stylesheets and such. Maybe you mean svg `<line>`? Or a `.link` class?

If it's not something simple like that, it could be your call to .data(), which returns all new data joins. Try passing in a key function as a second parameter to .data() to match how your data and elements are originally matched up. Something simple like the following may do it:

By not passing in this function, you're pairing all of your data to elements by index, which is the same as this:

```
   .data(force.links(), function(d, i) { return i })
```

Your existing joins may have been matched in some way other than by index.

[D3.js API - selection.data()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data)

Comment: "link" is class name. links is the same as force.links()

As you can see in my question, I create a new link as:

    link = {source: source, target: target};

I want to append text only to this link. How can I achieve that? I am reading the article you suggested, but still have not found the answer.

Comment: Then there's you're issue. As stated above, use `svg.selectAll(".link")`, not `svg.selectAll("link")`

Comment: But link is the class name of all links. Please see the end of my question. I have edited it.

Comment: Take a look at [this force graph by the main developer behind D3js](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), specifically at this part: 
`var link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(graph.links).enter().append("line")`. The `.enter()` returns all new joins and because no "link" elements exist, that is why text is rendering for every link. However, they are not only showing up for every link because the text is still reading the data for the links. Please try updating your script to select all elements by class name "link", which again, is `svg.selectAll(".link")`.

Comment: I used .link. It does not display any text. I have been trying various ways but not able to make it work. Please see 

http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347  

Click anywhere in the canvas. It creates a new node. Drag mouse from one node to another. It creates an arrow between the nodes. I want that a text should be displayed as label of an arrow just after the arrow is created. Text should be appended only to that arrow. What code to add in that?